# What JS do I use to preload the panel content for each tab before it's clicked on?

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-ui-tabs, preload

Right now I have some AJAX tabs that are loading external pages into an empty div when the tab is clicked, it creates a jerky movement since the div is empty and then quickly loads the content when your in the tab. Do you guys know a way to preload the pages so that they are already ready to go when someone clicks on a tab?

This is what I currently have so you can see what I mean..

http://testing.morecleanenergy.com/step_1

My current loading JS..

```
<script>
 $(document).ready(function(){
  $('#ajax-tab-container').easytabs();
});
</script>
```

Comment: I don't quite understand what you mean, could you explain it for me? thanks!

Comment: Put some default information in the div's or hide the whole thing until the div's are populated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#ajax-tab-container').easytabs();
  $("#tabs2").load('/tab2.html');
  $("#tabs3").load('/tab3.html');
  $("#tabs4").load('/tab4.html');
});
```

If you use classes for the #tabs you can do a for each here instead but if you have only 4 tabs above code shold be fine.

Comment: <div id="ajax-tab-container" class='tab-container'>
 <ul class='tabs'>
   <li class='tab'><a href="tab1.html" data-target="#tabs1">What is Solar Perks</a></li>
   <li class='tab'><a href="tab2.html" data-target="#tabs2">How it works</a></li>
   <li class='tab'><a href="tab3.html" data-target="#tabs3">Why CEC</a></li>
   <li class='tab'><a href="tab4.html" data-target="#tabs4">Community Solar</a></li>
 </ul>
 <div class='panel-container'>
  <div id="tabs1"></div>
  <div id="tabs2"></div>
  <div id="tabs3"></div>
  <div id="tabs4"></div>
 </div>
</div>

Comment: Blah, sorry can't figure out how to get it to show up nice in the comments.. thats my tabs html.

Comment: Yeah that's why I wrote it, if you call div.load after you call easytabs in your document ready, the tabs will load before you click on them so the first time you click on them they'll be ready?

Comment: Yah thats what I want to happen is to load before they click on the tab, I'll try it out!